# How can I configure these two Sonicwalls to exchange traffic?

Tags: networking, sonicwall

Site 1 has a TZ210 with a content filtered WAN.  Site 2 has TZ 105 and an unfiltered WAN. The end goal is to direct traffic from a VLAN on Site 2 to the WAN on Site 1.

From Site 1 I can ping to 10.3.10.4 but not 10.3.10.2.  From Site 2 Router I cannot ping 10.3.10.4, but it can ping itself on X4. From the LocoM2 10.3.10.4 I cannot ping 10.3.10.2.

When I direct connect a laptop to Site 2 X4 I can ping the interface.

What steps do I need to take to get these two routers to talk?

[image: WiFi Bridge]

This is a similar question to [another Serverfault qustion](https://serverfault.com/questions/528063/wireless-bridging-two-sonicwall-firewalls) without an answer

Answer (score 0):

How to: Setup a VPN tunnel and use it as default route for all
(Internet) >> http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/SOS2e_Route_all_Internet_traffic_through_this_SA.pdf

This is old image from earlier model, but the menu should be almost the same for the new model.

NOTE: This is an enhance firmware, so maybe it cost less to buy the add-on "Comprehensive Gateway Security Suite Bundle" for the TZ105 than having the enhance firmware.

Comment: Is a VPN really the right approach?  The distance between Site 1 and Site 2 is connected via directional WiFi antennae.  It's not the Internet.

Comment: @Sandy - It's WAN on both side, or just like a LAN extender ? Please give detail about that gear/connection

Comment: The directional antennae take the place of and perform the same service as an ethernet cable. Effectively Site 1 and Site 2 routers are directly connected. Sorry for not making that clear in my OP.

Comment: @Sandy np! first problem, route are bad in LocoM2 or the X4 interface is to strict in site2, please validate the config there if you can. You should able to talk to both site before you change WAN rule

Comment: Agreed. The problem is probably in Site 2 X4, as I can connect my laptop to the LAN side of 10.3.10.4 and ping back to 10.3.10.1 with no trouble.  Site 2 X4 interface is configured to allow management over HTTPS and ping.

Comment: @sandy  What model the locom gear is? As you dont need a internet connection on site2 at all, you could plug the locm gear in the lan side, and remove the tz105.

Comment: @yahmoth They are Ubiquiti Nanostation Loco M2.  I'd be happy to push all the traffic out the WAN on Site 1 but can't the connectivity to work.